# Configurable swatches on category page showing Out Of Stock Products

Tags: configurable-product, swatches, color-swatches, enterprise-1.14

I am working with a site and currently the configurable color swatches show every single out of stock associated products' swatch color on the **category** page, but not on the product info page.

Is this default behaviour for Enterprise? Is there a way to fix this? I can't imagine it being default behaviour since the product info page displays only the in-stock options.

Comment: Great, worked for me. Think Magento and some themes did not factor configurable product in building the list template

Answer (score 1):

You need to check product Stock  & skip out of stocks color to your list.

You can did following code on

> yourtheme/template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/list/swatches.phtml

```
$_product = $this->getProduct(); 
/* get available instock products */
$instockProductsId = array(); 
$usedProductsArray = array();
$skip = false;
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable") {
    $usedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
    foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) {
             if ($child->isSalable()) {
                    $instockProductsId[]  = $child->getId();
             }
    }
}

if(count($instockProductsId)>0){
    $skip = true;
        foreach($instockProductsId as $id){
            $color = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($id, 'color', $storeId);
            $usedProductsArray[$id] = $color;       
        }
}
$usedProductsArray = array_unique($usedProductsArray);
```

then add  if condition in  foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_attrValues as $_optionValue => $_optionLabel):   
/* To skip out of stock product on list page */   
    if($skip && !in_array($_optionValue,$usedProductsArray)){
        continue;
    }
endforeach;
```